# How to delete curves and lines from Pdf created using PDPageContentStream class in Pdfbox?

Tags: pdf, line, pdfbox, bezier

I have implemented functionality to allow user to add clouds and lines in a pdf using pdfbox library. I used the PDPageContentStream.addBezier312 and PDPageContentStream.lineTo functions to draw the markups. Now, I want to implement functionality to allow user to undo, delete and move drawn markups. And for that I need to implement functionality to delete the already saved curves, lines in the pdf. How, do I achieve this?

Comment: There's no simple answer because PDF files are not really made for editing... you'd need to parse the content stream to search for "your" curve. See the RemoveAllText.java example from the source code download to see how to get the tokens. Your curve is probably several numbers and "c", see in the PDF specification ("operator summary") and/or look at your file with PDFDebugger.

Comment: As you have developed that maybe you could utilize Marked-content operators i.e. wrap your specific operators into a BMC/EMC pair using a specific tag. This way you can identify your content within the already existing elements. This could be combined with having your content in a separate content stream. Or use annotations for that which you could also tag to identify yours.

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun Do you mean that, I create all my markups in different layers(Optional content group) and then delete the whole layer if required.

Comment: That's another option, but what I meant is using the marked content capability of PDF. You can read about it in 10.5 of the PDF 1.7 spec or 14.6 of ISO 32000-1 - just search for *MarkedContent*

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun Do you the COSName to be user for the BMC/EMC? I use COSName.OC for layers. I am not able to find any for marked content.

Comment: You can use https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.html#beginMarkedContent(org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName). As you don't use a predefined name and I think you don't want to register your name(s) with Adobe you can choose a name for yourself but you need to prefix it with XX. Details in Appendix E of PDF 1.7. Also consider using annotations instead of adding to the pages content stream as these will be individual objects which can be added/removed/edited easier and are made for such purposes.

Comment: Alternatively you could move your clouds and lines from the page content to annotations. Annotations are easy to move or delete.

Comment: @mkl So, instead of using  PDPageContentStream.beginMarkedContentSequence(COSName.OC,COSName.getPDFName(layerResourceName));  Shall, I use PDPageContentStream.beginMarkedContentSequence(COSName.ANNOTS,COSName.getPDFName(AnnotName)); ?

Comment: No, use an annotation to add your markup to the PDF instead of adding your markup to the page content stream. You can take a look at the AddAnnotations.java example in the examples package how to do that. There are different types of annotations which allow for different content.

Comment: If you'd really like to go for the marked content sequence - apart from annotations likely to be better suited for your needs - you can do `PDPageContentStream.beginMarkedContentSequence(COSName.getPDFName(String));` with `String` being an identifier you can freely choose but which should start with `XX`.

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun The markup that I am drawing has shape of cloud( a rectangle whose border is made up of curves). I did not find find any annotation that i satisfies this requirement, i.e. why I went with the PDPageContentStream approach.

Comment: What you are looking for is a Polygon annotation with a special intent called PolygonCloud. There is no specific support in PDFBox for that i.e. the appearance generation needs to be done by yourself as well as setting the specific keys for that. As you already have the code to generate the cloudy appearance there shouldn't be too much work to convert the code you have to utilize the annotation. The easiest is to generate such an annotation in Adobe Reader and compare the settings with your code.

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun I am using addBezier function of PDPageContentStream to create the polygon cloud.But for setting the appearance of markup, I need to create PDAppearance dictionary, which doesn't have any function related to drawing.

Comment: Yes, but the appearance stream, being part of the appearance dictionary,  can be passed to `PDPageContentStream(PDDocument doc, PDAppearanceStream appearance)`. I'll try to come up with a simple example later today but can only provide some pointers currently - sorry for that.

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun I am not able to create a PDAppearance stream as it requires a COS stream, which requires some access storage variable.Can you help?